# Incompatible types error in Command Prompt

Tags: java, class, command-prompt, composition, composite

I have a work about calculating the distances between two points. It consist of Point Class, Line Class as well as Main Class. The following is my Point class. After working on the private double distance(Point p) method, I am unable to return p at the public double getDistance(Point p) method. I run code on Command Prompt and it shows error: incompatible types: Point cannot be converted to double. Please advice.

```
class Point
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

//Constructor
public Point()
{
    //nothing
}

//Second constructor
public Point (int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

//Copy constructor
public Point (Point p)
{
    this (p.x, p.y);
}

private double distance(Point p)
{
    int dX = this.x - p.x;
    int dY = this.y - p.y;
    double result = Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
    return result;
}

public double getDistance(Point p)
{        
    return p;
}

//getter
public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}

//setter
public void set(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public String toString ()
{
    return String.format ("Given Point (%d, %d)", x, y);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the object Point `p` as your parameter and return it as a double.

In your block of code you're stating a return of the Object Point p and not a double data type.

```java
public double getDistance(Point p) {
   return p; 
}
```

If you're just trying to calculate the distance of the object, use your `distance()` method.  This method already returns the distance calculated as a `double`.

```java
private double distance(Point p) {
    int dX = this.x - p.x;
    int dY = this.y - p.y;
    double result = Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
    return result;
}
```